# image_url = sys.argv[1] IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am having an issue with the following section of Python code:

```
import sys  
import requests  
import firebase_admin  
from firebase_admin import credentials  
from firebase_admin import storage  
image_url = sys.argv[1]  
cred = credentials.Certificate('certificate.json')  
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred,{'storageBucket':'gs://rpi-demo-6d21d.appspot.com'})  
bucket = storage.bucket()  
image_data = requests.get(image_url).content  
blob = bucket.blob('happy.jpg')  
blob.upload_from_string(image_data,content_type='image/jpg')  
print(blob.public_url)
```

Specifically the error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "demo4.py", line 6, in <module>
image_url = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: The error is saying that you didn't pass an argument to `demo4.py` when invoking it. Make sure to pass all required arguments when calling it - `python demo4.py <url_goes_here>`.

Comment: can you help me with some examples ?

Comment: Often we use `if sys.argv[1:]: x = sys.argv[1]`.  In other words, first check the `sys` is large enough before trying to access an element.  If it isn't large enough define some sort of default, or raise an error.  It might help if you `print(sys.argv)` before trying to use it.  Experiment with various inputs.

Comment: Well, I have given you an example for your command, but an even smaller example is this: you can put ```import sys

print(sys.argv[1])``` into `demo.py` and try running it using `python demo.py`. You'll get ```$ python demo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range```, but if you add a command line argument, you'll get the correct output: ```$ python demo.py foo
foo```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys.argv` list is populated from the command line arguments passed to the script, so in case none are provided it's expected to get an error like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "demo4.py", line 6, in <module>
image_url = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

An easy repro is to put

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[1])
```

in `demo.py` and run it using `python demo.py`. You'll get the output

```
$ python demo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

but if you pass an argument to it using `python demo.py foo` you'll get the desired output:

```
$ python demo.py foo
foo
```

Specifically for your example, looks like when calling `demo4.py` script you're not passing image url command line argument. You can pass it using `python demo4.py <image_url_goes_here>`.

Comment: image_url = sys.argv[1]  #we pass the url as an argument , How to pass url and where i get the image url , because i want to upload image from my local storage ?

Comment: @shashankpatel, the script you're using seems to be uploading an image to a cloud blob storage, so you should provide the URL of the image you want to upload.